# Why doesn't */%/x match a/b/x, in a Makefile?

Tags: regex, makefile

Explained in Makefile code…

```
PATH = a/b/x
$(patsubst a/%/x,%,$(PATH))    # => b
$(patsubst */%/x,%,$(PATH))    # => a/b/x
```

It seems like both of these should produce the same result, `b`, as the `*` should match anything. Why is this not the case? How do I write one expression to capture the center term with *any* prefix, not just 'a'?

Comment: By the way, I would love to re-express this title somehow. Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Make simply doesn't have very good ability to handle wildcards. Your `$(patsubst */%/x,%,$(PATH))` doesn't work because there is no `*` in your `$(PATH)`. But you can get the effect you want with this kludge:

```
$(word 2, $(subst /, ,$(PATH)))
```